# createSenderView url always goes to the tagging page vs. the prepare page

Tags: docusignapi

I am able to generate the “createSenderView” url just fine.  But when I use the link, even with the “&send=0” parameter, I end up on the tagging page vs. the prepare page where I can upload more documents.  Why?

[Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____94)

Below is a sample of the link that I'm generating.

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=8899b1c1-1946-40d1-b907-9dd989f64d68&DocuEnvelope=ccf36a3f-fce0-4a9a-bc6c-76b4d44d0d4f&send=0

Please note that this link has already been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send=1 and send=0 both work properly in the Classic UI as well as New DocuSign Experience.

I would double check you do not have "Use Advanced Sending" ticked on the tagging screen as it will override the URL parameter. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Not sure why this is not documented within the API calls....Because at first glance this seems to be a bug within the API.

Comment: Completely agree, I'm not a fan of the verbiage in the webapp feature either. The typical rule is API settings > * but this is one unfortunately is an outlier.